# GCC C++11 Condition Variable Wait Internals

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm hunting down a bug we have with some messy thread/condition variable classes being updated to use C++11 threads.  During the course of the hunt, I've come across the following in the GCC codebase:

```
  template<typename _Lock>
  void
  wait(_Lock& __lock)
  {
    unique_lock<mutex> __my_lock(_M_mutex);
    _Unlock<_Lock> __unlock(__lock);
    // _M_mutex must be unlocked before re-locking __lock so move
    // ownership of _M_mutex lock to an object with shorter lifetime.
    unique_lock<mutex> __my_lock2(std::move(__my_lock));
    _M_cond.wait(__my_lock2);
  }
```

Despite the comment, I'm having difficulty understanding the purpose of the move constructor here to __my_lock2.  Why is __my_lock moved to __my_lock2 here?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with `__my_lock`'s destructor being called **after** `__unlock`'s, whereas `__my_lock2` will be destroyed first. It's basically hacking around FILO lifetime rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does not look like `condition_variable` code.  It looks like `condition_variable_any` code.  The latter has a templated wait function.  The former does not.

[N2406](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html#gen_cond_var) may shed light on what you are seeing.  In N2406, `condition_variable_any` is instead named `gen_cond_var`, but otherwise, the types are identical.  This paper describes a deadlock scenario whereupon deadlock is achieved unless great care is taken to assure that `_M_mutex` and `__lock` are locked and unlocked in a very specific order.

While the code you show, and the code at N2406, is not the same, I strongly suspect that they are both built to lock and unlock these two locks in an order so as to avoid the deadlock described in N2406.  Without further insight into the definition of `_Unlock`, I can not be absolutely certain though.  However a strong clue is the final comment in N2406 of the this wait function:

```
}  // mut_.unlock(), external.lock()
```

I.e. the member mutex must be unlocked prior to locking the external `__lock`.  By moving `__my_lock` to a local variable with scope less than that of `__unlock`, it is highly likely that the correct ordering of

```
}  // _M_mutex.unlock(), __lock.lock()
```

has been achieved.  To understand why this ordering is so critically important, you have to read the associated section of N2406 (it prevents deadlock).

Answer (score 3):

The function (which I believe to be `std::condition_variable_any<_Lock>::wait`) is avoiding deadlock by establishing a lock ordering invariant that `__lock` must be locked before acquiring `_M_mutex`. While doing so, it must somehow still guarantee that `__lock` is not held while waiting on the internal condition variable `_M_cond`. Note that `_Unlock<_Lock>` is an RAII **unlocking** object. It performs the opposite function of the usual lock guards by *unlocking* in its constructor and *locking* in the destructor. The necessary ordering of events is:

1. acquire `__lock` (pre-condition of the `wait` call)
2. acquire `_M_mutex` (in the `__my_lock` constructor)
3. release `__lock` (in the `__unlock` constructor)
4. atomically release `_M_mutex` and wait on `_M_cond` (happens in `_M_cond.wait`)
5. reacquire `_M_mutex` on wakeup (also in `_M_cond.wait`)
6. release `_M_mutex` (in the `__my_lock2` destructor)
7. reacquire `__lock` (in the `__unlock` destructor)

The move from `__my_lock` to `__my_lock2` is necessary so that `__my_lock2` will be destroyed before `__unlock` ensuring that event 6 happens before 7 instead of after.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is to reorder the destruction of the `__lock` and `__my_lock` variables.

The calls should look like this:

```
construct __my_lock // locks   _M_mutex
construct __unlock  // unlocks __lock
construct __my_lock2 // Does nothing as its a move.

_M_cond.wait(__my_lock2);

destroy __mylock2 // unlocks __M_mutex
destroy __unlock // locks __lock again
destroy __mylock // does nothing as its been moved
```

Without the move the order would be

```
construct __my_lock // locks   _M_mutex
construct __unlock  // unlocks __lock

_M_cond.wait(__my_lock);

destroy __unlock // locks __lock
destroy __mylock // unlocks _M_mutex
```

Which can result in deadlock as mentioned in the other answer